# Save macro enabled document as new template

Tags: vba, ms-word

I created a Word 2010 template with macros and VBA code but then I amended one of the documents created from the template instead of the template and this included text boxes and drop down lists.  How do I save the document as a new template with the macros maintained as well as the VBA and components such as text boxes etc.  When I try and save the document as a .dotm file the option to place in Design Mode doesn't work and I have took the document out of Compatibility Mode.

Comment: Save the new document as a macro enabled template. Copy the code from the original template to the new one. You can do that by dragging modules from one project to the other in VBE's Project Explorer while both templates are open. Export & Import or Copy/Paste will also work.

Comment: @Variatus Thanks for response.  I tried this and it creates the template okay with the components created in the amended document from the original template but the remaining trouble is when I create a document from the new template the drop downs and the edit boxes are NOT editable.  How do I resolve this part please

Comment: A document's VBA code resides in its attached template. Make sure that the new document has the new template as `AttachedTemplate` (Developer tab -> Add-ins). Not that I would see how this could affect the functionality of your text boxes unless they are disabled by code which fails to run. Your original question seems to point at a problem with compatibility between versions. Try to ensure that the new template is made in the same version of Word in which you want to create documents from it.

Comment: @Variatus thanks again so far. I checked a new document has the correct attached template in Developer >> Ad-ins and regarding compatibility the template and subsequent new documents were both created in Word 2010 but still it doesn't work.

Comment: What are the "VBA components such as text boxes" which you have added to the document? ActiveX controls? Legacy controls? Content controls? Some of these controls you could actually just copy from the document and paste into the original template. How should I understand "the drop downs ... are not editable"? Do you mean you can't change their properties? Or can't use them?

Comment: @Variatus The VBA components- I mean by that the components that I have added VBA code behind them and these are all button controls so they are ActiveX controls.  The Drop Down List controls are from the basic controls available in the actual Ribbon under Developer >> Controls.  I have tried copy and pasting everything I am happy with from the .docm document to the .dotm template BUT when I double click the template to create new document from the template the dropdown lists and the text boxes ONLY show the last value in the template and the dropdown lists do not drop down to show the options